# Show that a set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and determine basis and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have to show that the sets
$$
H_1=\{(x, y, z, w)\in\mathbb{R}^4:2x+3y+5z-w=0\}
$$
and
$$
H_2=\{(x, y, z, w)\in\mathbb{R}^4:x+3y-w=2x-4z+6w=0\}
$$
are subspaces and I have to determine a basis and the dimension.

**My attempt.** I easily verify that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Moreover, $H_1$ is given by the solutions of the linear system of the only equation
$$
2x+3y+5z-3w=0.
$$
This system has $\infty^3$ solutions. For any choice of
$$
y = s,\quad z = t, \quad w = r
$$
there is a solution and it is
$$
\left(-\frac{3}{2}s-\frac{5}{2}t+\frac{1}{2}r, s, t, r\right)=s\left(-\frac{3}{2}, 1, 0, 0\right)+t\left(-\frac{5}{2}, 0, 1, 0\right)+r\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0, 0, 1\right).
$$
So a basis can be $\left\{\left(-\frac{3}{2}, 1, 0, 0\right), \left(-\frac{5}{2}, 0, 1, 0\right), \left(\frac{1}{2}, 0, 0, 1\right)\right\}$ and the dimension of $H_1$ is $3$.

The same for $H_2$. The associated linear system has $\infty^2$ solutions. For any choice of
$$
z = s, \quad w = t
$$
there is a solution and it is
$$
\left(2s-3t, -\frac{2}{3}s+\frac{4}{3}t, s, t\right)=s\left(2, -\frac{2}{3}, 1, 0\right)+t\left(-3, \frac{4}{3}, 0, 1\right).
$$
So a basis can be $\left\{\left(2, -\frac{2}{3}, 1, 0\right), \left(-3, \frac{4}{3}, 0, 1\right)\right\}$ and the dimension of $H_2$ is $2$.

Is my attempt right?

Thank You

Comment: What are $\infty^2$ and $\infty^3$?

Comment: The "number" of solutions. Powers $2$ and $3$ denote the number of free parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $2s-3t$ and not $2s+3t$ for the $x$ coordinate of $H_2$. Adjust the rest in consequence, apart from that, your approach is perfectly adapted.

You also swapped the $x$ coordinates depending on $s$ and $t$ for $H_2$.

Comment: Now all should be ok. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct, for the dimension as you noted we have one condition for $H_1$ and 2 independent conditions for $H_2$ thus the dimensions are $3$ and $2$, to check the bases we can plug the basis vector in the given equations and verify that they works fine.